# Как закрыть внешнюю программу с помощью python

Tags: python

Мне нужно закрыть программу (любую) с помощью python. Я знаю что можно открывать программы с помощью os.startfile, но как закрывать программы, нигде не могу найти.

Comment: Запускайте через subprocess.Popen, он возвращает объект процесса. Через этот же объект можно процесс и убить.

Comment: @insolor спасибо, но можете более подробно рассказать как убить процесс:)

Comment: С помощью метода [terminate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) объекта Popen. Или kill, если нужно немедленно убить процесс без штатного его завершения.

Comment: @insolor спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать это:

```
os.system('taskkill /f /im **название процесса**.exe')
```

Comment: Этот код выдаёт `AttributeError`.

Comment: @wchistow потому что там буква пропущена. Я исправил.

Comment: Да, пропустил буковку 